# What is a good asymptotic for $f_n = f_{n-1}+\ln(f_{n-1})$?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Let $f_0=2$ and $f_n=f_{n-1}+\ln(f_{n-1})$. What is a good asymptotic to the sequence $f_n$? With good I mean much better than $f_n \sim \dfrac{3n \ln(2)\ln(n)}{2}$.

Comment: How much better do you need it? Apparently you have the leading order already figured out, as well as the accompanying leading order constant.

Comment: Well for instance a term like $\sqrt ln(ln(n))$ would be nice.

Comment: Could you provide some details about your calculation?
Maybe someone will be able to develop your idea and could derive more terms.

Comment: @vesszabo even that calculation is not formal. Handwaving stuff. Since it cannot be of the form n^a for a>1 and it must grow faster than O(n) we get C n ln(n) because of the finiteness of elementary functions. Not very formal hmm. I basically used elimination.

Comment: $f_n / n\log(n)$ doesn't appear to be constant asymptotically, suggesting that the form you arrived at could indeed be improved.

Comment: The analogous continuos ODE $f' = \ln f$ leads to $f = \exp ( E_i^{-1} [(c+x) e^c ]-c)$ where $E_i^{-1}$ is the inverse of the exponential integral function. But its asymptotics are ugly, see answer and linked paper:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94860/inverse-function-of-operatornamelix-over-x-mu

Comment: @leonbloy your ODE has the main solution : functional inverse of $li(x)$. Since $li(x)$ is well approximated by $\dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}$ , the inverse is about $x \ln(x)$. This suggests the main term for $f_n$ is $n \ln(n)$. I assume the difference between that main term and $ f_n$ is of the form $(A \cdot n \ln(n))^B$ where $B$ is probably $\frac{1}{2}$. If you disagree plz explain. Note however that even the ODE is just an approximation , so we need to be carefull with approximating an approximation !

Comment: Inverse of Li does seem to be the proper asymptotic.  Indeed, $f_{20000} = 224080.77$ and $\mathrm{Li}(224080.77) = 19999.6$.  And first-order for the inverse of Li is $n \log n$, constant 1, as Dld says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{f_n}n-\log n-\log\log n\right)=-1$$

To prove this, consider $g_n=n\log n+n\log\log n-n$ and $h_n=f_n-g_n$. One wants to prove that $h_n=o(n)$. The identity $f_{n+1}=f_n+\log f_n$ is equivalent to
$$
h_{n+1}=g_n+h_n+\log(g_n+h_n)-g_{n+1}.
$$
Using simple properties of the logarithm, one can show that this implies
$$
h_{n+1}=h_n+\log\left(1+\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}-\frac1{\log n}+\frac{h_n}{n\log n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{\log n}\right).
$$
In particular, if $h_n=o(n\log n)$, the logarithm in the RHS goes to zero hence $h_{n+1}=h_n+o(1)$, which implies $h_n=o(n)$. Thus, our task is to prove the easier statement that
$$
f_n=n\log n+o(n\log n).
$$
To do so, first note that $f_n\geqslant2$ for every $n\geqslant0$ yields $f_{n+1}-f_n\geqslant\log2$ hence $f_n\geqslant n\log2$ for every $n\geqslant0$. Plugging this once again in the recursion $f_{n+1}=f_n+\log f_n$ yields $f_{n+1}-f_n\geqslant\log n+\log\log2$ hence, summing up, $f_n\geqslant n\log n+o(n\log n)$.

In the other direction, $f_{k+1}-f_k=\log f_k\leqslant\log f_n$ for every $k\leqslant n$ hence $f_n\leqslant f_0+n\log f_n$, which can be seen to imply $f_n\leqslant n\log n+2n\log\log n$ for every $n$ large enough. This completes the proof.

Comment: I confess I haven't checked all the steps, but it looks nice.

Comment: Interestingly, this result does not agree with the OP lead term coefficient (though the difference is numerically small $1.0397$ instead of $1$), and it agrees with what I had got with a ODE approximation (see my comment in the question; I didn't post it because it lacked rigour, and only gave the first asymptotic term)

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks. Regarding your confession... *ego te absolvo a peccatis tuis. Amen.*

Comment: Could you show more detailed steps plz ?

Comment: Could you ask more focused questions in comments, thanks? By the way, here is a focused question: where did you find the factor $3\ln(2)/2$ in your post?

Comment: @Did that was a mistake. It seemed to fit for small values and I jumped into conclusions... almost since it was a question NOT an answer :)

Comment: I forgot to upvote it ! Did it today :)