# A Regularized Beta function limit: $\lim_{a\to0}\frac{1-\text I_\frac zb(a,b)}a$

Tags: calculus, limits, special-functions, closed-form, beta-function

The goal is to “generalize” the [Exponential Integral $\text{Ei}(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expintegralei) using [the Regularized Beta function $\text I_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Betaregularized+):

$$f(b,z)=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{1-\text I_\frac zb(a,b)}a$$

Some clues include:

$$\boxed{f(0,z)\mathop=^\text{lim} \lim_{\begin{matrix}
a\to0\\
b\to\infty
\end{matrix}}\frac{1-\text I_\frac zb(a,b)}a=-\text{Ei}(-z)}$$

$$f(1,z)=-\ln(z)$$

$$f(2,z)=\frac z2-\ln\left(\frac z2\right)-1$$

$$f(3,z)=-\frac{z^2}{18}+\frac{2z}3-\ln\left(\frac z3\right)-\frac32$$

$$f(4,z)=\frac{z^3}{192}-\frac{3z^2}{32}+\frac{3z}4-\ln(z)+\ln(4)-\frac{11}6$$

Is there a closed form for $$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{1-\text I_\frac zb(a,b)}a?$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: @metamorphy It transforms into $\text B_{1-\frac z b}(b,0)$ which is also a lerch transcendent. It seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice there is a [Lerch Transcendent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lerchphi) and an [Incomplete Beta function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28z%2Ca%2Cb%29). After using an integral representation, we get the final answer of:

$$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{1-\text I_\frac zb(a,b)}a=-\text B_{1-\frac zb}(b,0)=\left(1-\frac zb\right)^b\Phi\left(1-\frac zb,1,b\right)$$

Therefore:

$$-\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(1+\frac zb\right)^b\Phi\left(1+\frac zb,1,b\right)=\text{Ei}(z)$$

For $b\in\Bbb N$, the function gives a more accurate series expansion for $\text{Ei}(z)$

Of course, now we can use [Inverse Beta Regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversebetaregularized+) with a limit to invert a branch of the exponential integral without having to use [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94860/inverse-function-of-operatornamelix-over-x-mu/4388151#4388151). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Feel free to answer with any other insights